# Message() in R - using output to be passed as message inpuut

Tags: r, message, radix

I am writing in if statement, which checks for duplicated. If there are any I want to continue executing, but return a message indicating which are the duplicates. I tried the `message()`, but I am unsure how to include the values of `locations`.

```
 if(anyDuplicated(regionGroups$location) > 0){
   duplicateRegions <- regionGroups[, 'count' := .N, by = location][count > 1, .SD[1], by = location][[1]]
   message("Location is not unique in the table regionGroups. There are length(duplicateRegions) duplicated locations, namely: duplicateRegions[1],duplicateRegions[2]  ")
   regionGroups <- regionGroups[!duplicated(regionGroups$location)]
 }


(anyDuplicated(regionGroups$location) > 0)
[1] TRUE

duplicateRegions
[1] 55100 26080
```

The desired output is:

```
Location is not unique in the table regionGroups. There are 2 duplicated locations, namely: 55100, 26080
```

The complicated thing is there may be many more duplicatedRegions and the numbers will change.

**QUESTION**: how to write the `message()` statement such that the output will list the respective values of `duplicateRegions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi does this work for you? I'm a little unsure as to why you need the `if` statement if you are going to execute anyway as there appears to be no `else` element required, perhaps you have left this out for simplicity.

Another point to note is that the `duplicated` does not pick up the first of the duplicates in the duplicated set so when you use: 
`regionGroups[!duplicated(regionGroups$location),]` it will always eliminate all but the first duplicate. That maybe ok for you but just as a warning.

Also if you take this approach: `namely: duplicateRegions[1],duplicateRegions[2]` in the message function you are assuming you know how many duplicates you will have which would not be the case. You can just collapse the string with: `paste(as.character(regionGroups$location[dups]), collapse = ", "))` so you don't need to worry about that.

```
if(any(duplicated(regionGroups$location))){
  dups <- which(duplicated(regionGroups$location))
  dup_regions <- regionGroups$location[dups]
  message(" Location is not unique in the table regionGroups. There are ", 
          length(dups)," duplicated locations, namely: ", paste(as.character(regionGroups$location[dups]), collapse = ", "))
  regionGroups <- regionGroups[!duplicated(regionGroups$location),]
}
```

Comment: yup, it was just for simplicity, but good eye :). actually i have a follow up question: for some reason when i run call dups i get `[1] 55100 26080` but then inside the `as.character` statement, i get `[1] NA NA`, any idea why?

Comment: It's probably because you have run the if statement once already. If you then run `as.character(regionGroups$location[dups])` those duplicate locations don't exist anymore. Just edited the second paragraph